# How to use webpack?

Tags: webpack

I am currently using webpack and i dont know how to correctly organize my project.
Lets say i have a Home page and Contact page.In Home page i want to use bootstrap and jquery but in Contact page i want to use bulma and vue.

1. Should i create with webpack, one js file and one css that contain bootstrap-jquery-bulma-vue and attach it on home page OR
2. Create two js-css files for each page?

Comment: You probably don't need Vue for a contact page

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance it's better to keep assets size for each page as small as possible.

Also mixing css frameworks is a bad practice, it will lead to multiple implementation of each components like grid, form, dropdown, modal, etc.
And even worse, different css frameworks will assign styles to html tags like `<p>`, `<button>`, `<h1>`, etc. It may produce conflicts and not desired styling.

Mixing jquery with vue is not so bad, but if not necessary then better not to use them together

So i recommend you to create entry point for each page in webpack